# How to pass an integer value using ViewData in asp.net mvc and then use value stored in ViewData to compare with another integer value in the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

For eg.

I want to do something like this in the controller :

```
ViewData["dummy"] = 100;
```

and then in the view I wish to compare its value like :

```
@if(ViewData["dummy"] = 100)
{
// do some stuff
}
```

Currently if I do this, I get an error saying -

```
Operator "==" cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'
```

Comment: Replace   @if(ViewData["dummy"] = 100) to  @if(Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["dummy"]))==100

Comment: @OleEHDufour It still gives me a run-time exception saying - InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[System.Int32]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Answer (score 3):

Try 
    `if((int)ViewData["dummy"] == 100)`

but I would also add a null check and some kind of "safe casting  helper method" so that you would be able to call i.e.

```
if(Helper.GetTyped<int>(ViewData["dummy"]) == 100)
```

or you can pass that value in a typed ViewModel

code I've just tested:

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}

<p>
    @if ((int)ViewData["dummy"] == 100)
    {
        <h1> 100</h1>
    }
</p>
```

controller:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
    ViewData["dummy"] = 100;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: @oneinaminion can you please show the controller code? this has to work

Answer (score 0):

I tried storing the integer value in ViewData and then doing

```
ViewData["dummy"].ToString() == "integer_value_here";
```

So basically, while comparing values in the view, I converted them to string and then compared and it works!!

Answer (score 0):

It is better to compare values using their own data types, so if you can pass the `int` value from controller within the model as `int` it will be better, but if you only can pass it within `ViewData` you can convert it to `int` within the view with `int.TryParse`:

```
@if(int.TryParse(ViewData["dummy"].ToString(), out int intValue))
{
    if(intValue==100)
    {
    <p>values are equal</p>
    }
    else
    {
    <p>values not equal</p>
    }
}
else
{
<p>value is not an integer</p>
}
```